# Excel Interop, iterating workbook for worksheet and chart

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, excel-interop

I have a scenario while working with Microsoft Excel Interop.

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator wsEnumerator = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.GetEnumerator();
while (wsEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    wsCurrent = (Excel.Worksheet)wsEnumerator.Current;
    //Worksheet operation Follows   
}
```

I am operating on Worksheets, so i can not have Chart in this. What i want to do achieve is operate on Sheets and check if it is a Worksheet or Chart, and act accordingly.

As sheets contain both Worksheet, Chart and "Excel 4.0 Macro", so what is the type of Sheets each entry as it can hold any of the type mentioned.

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator wsEnumerator = workBookIn.Sheets.GetEnumerator();
while (wsEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    //Identify if its a chart or worksheet
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by checking type of Current Enumerator

```
var item = wsEnumerator.Current;                   
if (item is Excel.Chart)
{
    //Do chart operations
}
else if (item is Excel.Worksheet)
{
    //Do sheetoperations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write the entire code (without enumerator):

```
foreach (dynamic sheet in workBookIn.Sheets)
{
    if (sheet is Chart)
        // Write your code
    else if (sheet is Worksheet)
        // Write your code
}
```